# Use Python to modify specific columns in csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of data in a `.csv` like this:

```
-959.378170,-0.000026,-94.960000,1508.000000,9.000000,
-958.978170,-0.000026,-94.920000,1508.000000,9.000000,
-958.578170,-0.000026,-94.880000,1508.000000,10.000000,
-958.178170,-0.000026,-94.840000,1508.000000,10.000000,
-957.778170,-0.000026,-94.800000,1508.000000,10.000000,
```

The last two columns are supposed to be time. `15` is the hour, `08` is the minute, `6` is the second. The end goal is to join them so that I get something like:

```
-958.978170,-0.000026,-94.920000,15:08:09,                
-958.578170,-0.000026,-94.880000,15:08:10,
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The python tutorial is a good start.  Then take a look at the csv and datetime modules. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`regex`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html)

```
import fileinput
import re

# Assume the input file is foo.csv
for line in fileinput.FileInput('foo.csv', inplace=1):
    mm = re.search(r'^(.+?,.+?,.+?,)(\d{1,2})(\d{2})\.0+,(\d{1,2})\.0+',
        line)
    g1, g2, g3, g4 = mm.group(1), int(mm.group(2)), int(mm.group(3)), int(mm.group(4))
    print "%s%02i:%02i:%02i," % (g1, g2, g3, g4)
```

Running this on the example results in...

```
-959.378170,-0.000026,-94.960000,15:08:09,
-958.978170,-0.000026,-94.920000,15:08:09,
-958.578170,-0.000026,-94.880000,15:08:10,
-958.178170,-0.000026,-94.840000,15:08:10,
-957.778170,-0.000026,-94.800000,15:08:10,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to read the `.csv` file (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for examples), and the [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method to parse the two columns into `datetime` objects, which you can then write out to whatever format you'd like (using `datetime.strftime`).

See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) section of the `datetime` docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the read_csv() method in pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files).

It has a great date parsing utility that allows you to bring strings from multiple columns together.